# calling a function with a table constructor?

Tags: lua

i was learning on how to create and use a class on a youtube video and i came across this code

```
cc = {calo = 0, goal = 1500}
function cc:new(t)
t = t or {}
setmetatable(t,self)
self.__index = self
return t
end
a = cc:new{goal = 100}
```

i dont understand this part `a = cc:new{goal = 100}` this is the first time where i see a function being called with anything other then `()`. i have 2 guesses on what this does maybe it replaces the parameter of `cc:new` function with `{goal = 100}` or maybe the function is called and `t` table is assigned to the variable then assigning the table with `{goal = 100}`? pls correct me if im wrong

Comment: That's explained here: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.10. It's calling the function with one argument.

Comment: i tried to google calling functions with {} but couldnt find anything so thnx 4 the link

Comment: so if i understand correctly, doing ```cc:new{goal = 100}``` is syntax sugar for ```cc:new({goal = 100})``` and when the function is called this happens? ```function cc:new({goal = 100}) t = {goal = 100} or {}```, the parameters passed to the function only replaces the rvalue in the function body right?

Comment: Parameters are really just local variables, so yes, you can reassign them like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, `{goal = 100}` is just an argument.

second, `cc:new{goal = 100}` is equal to `cc:new({goal = 100})`

this is a **syntactic sugar**, you can call a function without brackets if theres only one argument and its type is **string** or **table** literal

example:

```lua
function foo(x)
    print(x)
    return foo
end

foo "Hello" "World"
```

this will output "Hello" and "World"

if you want to call a function without brackets and using multiple arguments, the function you gonna call must return another function for the next argument.

**the another function is not always the original one**

it may be recursive

Comment: thnx 4 the answer